# SLIM 3 : PHP Variables

Tags: php, slim

im using slim for the first time and want to know why i get undefined in $file variable. Do i have to add the variables to the container or how it works? How the cycle works?, neither work if i add var_dump inside the get.

In another area of the site i use define, but i think it´s not the best way.

Hope you can help.

```
$app->get('/path/{id}-{title}', function ($request, $response, $args) {

switch ($args['id']) {
    case '1':
        $file = 'pathtofile';
        break;
    case '2':
        $file = 'pathtofile2';
        break;
}

var_dump($args);

return $this->view->render($response, $file.'.html', [
    'id' => $args['id'],
    'title' => $args['title']
]);
})->setName('path');
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump($args)`? I think `$args['id']` is neither 1 nor 2, so `$file` has not been created.

Comment: Agree with the above, what does your `var_dump($args)` return?

Comment: Figured out what's happening, in the url sent ex: 1-curso-internacional i added multiple ' - ' because of that it get's confused about the path '/path/{id}-{title}'. Solved using first ' - ' besides ' _ ' ( 1-curso_internacional ). I thought that was not going to give problems

Comment: Just define what id could be as an regex: `/path/{id:\d+}`, means that id only can hold numbers. [ref](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute#usage)

Comment: It's a good practice to explicitly handle default case in a switch, it helps you prevent similar problems.